# How can I generate a Parsing Error in BitBake on intent?

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I use Anonymous Python Functions in BitBake recipes to set variables during parsing.
Now I wonder if I can check if a specific variable is set or not. If not, then I want to generate a BitBake Error, which stops the build process.

Pseudo code, that I want to create:

```
python __anonymous () {
    if d.getVar('MY_VARIABLE', True) == "":
        <BITBAKE ERROR with custom message "MY_VARIABLE not found">
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can call `bb.fatal("MY_VARIABLE not set")` which will print that error and abort the build by throwing an exception.

Beware that d.getVar() returns `None` when the variable is unset. You only get the empty string if that's your default value.

Comment: Exactly what I searched and thanks for the hint with "None".

Answer (score 5):

Outputs are possible on different loglevels and with python as well as shell script code
For usage in python there are:

- **bb.fatal**
- bb.error
- bb.warn
- bb.note
- bb.plain
- bb.debug

For usage in shell script there are:

- **bbfatal**
- bberror
- bbwarn
- bbnote
- bbplain
- bbdebug

for example if you want to throw an error in your recipe's do_install_append function:

```
bbfatal "something went terribly wrong!"
```